# How can I switch from Trinity Desktop to KDE Plasma and viceversa?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, session

I remember one time I had GNOME, Xfce and KDE and in order to switch from one desktop environment to the other I had to pick one up at login screen or edit a file, but I can't remember the file anymore. Is there a way to easily switch between TDE and Plasma?

I'm using Kubuntu 18.10 Cosmic, KDE Plasma 5.15.4 and have just installed TDE 14.0.6.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I select my chosen DE at login.  It's by far the easiest, and is often a gear type button on the screen you press to see the list (how this shows depends on what greeter/dm you are running)

Answer (score 0):

I found out now. I just want to share some thoughts on Kubuntu. I've been using Ubuntu since around 2008, if I remember correctly, I started with a really brutish GNOME on Ubuntu 8.04, but it wasn't until I tried KDE that I learnt to love Linux. And now, how far we've come. The internet with its modern logo designs, and here I am back at the software I used to enjoy, Amarok 1.4, KDE 3.5. It's almost like going back to the past, but thanks to Trinity they're working once again, and the HD wallpapers, well, I used to have a huge outstanding collection of HD wallpapers most of which I had to delete with my system, never knowing how good they were, and now I'm back at finding good pics to fill my desktop. Some are even mine, not that good, but at least they're mine. And I remember that website "The Linux Game Tome", at happypenguin.org, designed solely to count all working games on Linux. Most were bad, and overall, the games were few. Now there's all the power of Steam and Linux, and though it's still a bit hard to configure for newbs like I was before, the results can be amazing. You get a fully functional system with all the benefits of security and freedom. Huge, huge respect for all those Linux developers, designers, sysadmins, users, and so on, out there, you're doing the best of jobs.

Now
https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/47682815201_fd91881d64_o.png

and then
https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/33805397798_025807f51b_b.jpg

Comment: How is this answer related to the question "*Is there a way to easily switch between TDE and Plasma?*"? It seems to be an essay on TDE and isn't the answer to your question.

Comment: Based on [this](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/3072/248158), I'm downvoting this answer in its present form.

Comment: Well, like guiverc said. You can choose at login. I defaulted to Trinity's session manager and from there I can pick up either Plasma or TDE. Now if there's a way to do that from Plasma, I'm not sure since I'm not using Plasma's Session Manager.

Comment: My point is that everything from "I just want to share" onward is not related to the question. Now, if the question was something like "What is the Trinity Desktop and why should I use it", your answer maybe relevant. Please see the section titled "Answer the question" in [How do I write a good answer?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) which has this: "Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative."